# Why is the Gentleman with thistledown hair brought to Vinculus?

Tags: jonathan-strange-and-mr-norrell

Towards the end of the Novel *Jonathan Strange and Mr. Norrell*, the fairy gentleman with thistledown hair invokes a magic spell to transport himself (and Stephen Black) to whomever poses the greatest threat to him. To his surprise (and ours), he is not brought to one of the titular magicians, but instead to the street magician Vinculus.

Why? Does Vinculus pose the greatest threat to him because he carries the prophecy of the return of English magic? Or was Vinculus only there by happenstance, and they were actually being transported to someone else - maybe John Uskglass the Raven King was there, but concealed by magic? Or maybe it was some kind of transportation to Stephen Black, as he was the one to eventually kill the fairy?

I don't really find any of the above guesses compelling - is there a clear answer?

Comment: https://hurtfew.mywikis.wiki/wiki/Vinculus

Answer (score 3):

The spell works and the Gentleman is brought to the person who poses the greatest threat to him: Stephen Black. It's just that they were already together and the Gentleman is oblivious to this fact. The arrival of Vinculus is a distraction or a reminder of the prophesy:  "*the nameless slave shall be a king in a strange country ...*"

Stephen Black being the greatest threat is shown when, later in the book

> Stephen Black kills the Gentleman and becomes the King of the Gentleman's kingdom of Lost Hope

Comment: I don't have the book handy at the moment, but I seem to recall both Stephen Black and the Gentleman being transported by the spell. Is there a reason that would happen? It seems like if it was just bringing the Gentleman to Stephen it would be simpler to do nothing, or move him a few feet closer?

Comment: Well, it's magic. Doesn't have to follow any specific reasoning.